# How do I debug an APK that is signed for release?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a release APK which I have signed, uploaded to Google Play and installed on my Android device. I would like to debug this APK (by means of Android Studio or Eclipse) whilst it is running on my Android device. I have done this before and I remember it being with one of the Android development tools (perhaps Dalvik Debug Monitor). Sadly, I cannot remember how to do it and I have been unable to find any articles online. Does anybody know how I can do this?

##### Notes

1. I have set `android:debuggable="true"` in the app's manifest file.
2. I have enabled USB Debugging on my Android device.

Comment: what are you currently trying? Do you not know how to use the Devices View in Eclipse?

Comment: I now have the Devices view showing in Eclipse. I can see my device in the Devices list. I click on it but the "Debug the selected process" button is disabled despite the application running on the phone and the source project being present and opened in the workspace. Any ideas?!

Comment: Are you clicking on the package name for your app?

Comment: Yes. See comment in your answer. (Thanks for the help btw. Appreciate it.)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Be sure that `android:debuggable="true"` is set in the `application` tag of your manifest file, and then:

1. Plug your phone into your computer and enable USB debugging on the phone
2. Open eclipse and a workspace containing the code for your app
3. In Eclipse, go to Window->Show View->Devices
4. Look at the Devices view which should now be visible, you should see your device listed
5. If your device isn't listed, you'll have to track down the ADB drivers for your phone before continuing
6. If you want to step through code, set a breakpoint somewhere in your app
7. Open the app on your phone
8. In the Devices view, expand the entry for your phone if it isn't already expanded, and look for your app's package name.
9. Click on the package name, and in the top right of the Devices view you should see a green bug along with a number of other small buttons. Click the green bug.
10. You should now be attached/debugging your app.

Comment: I get up to step 8 but for some reason my app's package name doesn't show when I'm running the signed/release apk. (Strangely it does show when I run the app (debug apk) on my phone straight from Eclipse.) Confused...

Comment: Got it! I had put the `android:debuggable="true"` attribute in the `manifest` tag instead of the `application` tag within manifest!! My bad :( Thanks Sam_D ever so much for your guidance. Wouldn't have done it without you, or at best would have taken a heck of a long time!

Comment: When I add the debuggable keyword in build.gradle and want to publish in play store it shows this error `You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. `

Comment: This answer is way outdated. Instead of `androidManifest.xml` you should update `build.gradle`. See other answers.

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 173):

I know this is old question, but future references. In Android Studio with Gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

The line `debuggable true` was the trick for me.

Before Gradle 1.0 it was `runProguard` instead of `minifyEnabled`. Look at [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0).

Comment: Note that as of gradle 1.0 it's **minifyEnabled** instead of **runProguard** - see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Comment: As a note to this current answer, I myself would avoid sending a debuggable release to the Google Play store, and it may not let you as in hasnain_ahmad's case in previous outdated answer. Just doing it temporarily to test a release-downloaded-from-store issue, like inapp purchase code tracking, would be less risky. You could also try working with the beta track (I don't know if this may give the same error as hasnian got) or transferring the release build apk to your phone from your computer to avoid the security issues (dealing with the bundle is messier).

Comment: That doesn' t look to work anymore (when `debuggable` is set to `true`, the release is not signed). https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622555/1720199

Answer (score 44):

Besides Manuel's way, you can still use the Manifest.

In Android Studio stable, you have to add the following 2 lines to `application` in the `AndroidManifest` file:

```
    android:debuggable="true"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"
```

The first one will enable debugging of signed APK, and the second one will prevent compile-time error.

After this, you can attach to the process via "Attach debugger to Android process" button.

[image]

Comment: @jaibatrik it has to be your apk and you have to attach the debugger from the sources. if you are doing both and it still does not work, share more info and I may try to help

Comment: I got "[Fatal Error] :7:203: The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:ignore" associated with an element type "application" is not bound." Is tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode" a legit config here?

Comment: I had to add `lintOptions { abortOnError false }` into my app/build.grade instead of using `tools:ignore` like so:

```android {
lintOptions: {
abortOnError false
}
}```

Comment: i got `The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:ignore" associated with an element type "application" is not bound.`
!

Answer (score 13):

I tried with the following and it's worked:

```
release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: This answer has already been given in this thread by Manuel Lopera... three years ago! See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181562/1071320

Comment: @AdilHussain But I tried that answer it's not worked for me. See there is a difference in my answer at ` minifyEnabled false` and it is `runProguard true` in his case. Please see the changes

Comment: Not a big deal but his answer does contain an update to this effect. Anyway. Not a big deal. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 13):

In case of you decided the debug *your* apk which is already in market but not assigned to be debuggable and you do not want to publish it again. So follow the below steps;

1. Decompile the Apk with [ApkTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)(eg. `apktool d <APK_PATH>`)
2. Open the AndroidManifest.xml from decompiled files
3. Set `android:debuggable="true"` in `application` tag
4. Compile the modified source with ApkTool (eg. `apktool b <MODIFIED_PATH>`)
5. Debuggable apk ready(which unsigned means cannot publish store). You can debug as you wish.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to your app build.gradle and select the specified release build variant and run

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'keyalias'
            keyPassword 'keypwd'
            storeFile file('<<KEYSTORE-PATH>>.keystore')
            storePassword 'pwd'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
          debuggable true
          signingConfig signingConfigs.config
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Add `debuggable true` in `release` in `buildTypes` and turn on 'release' in botton left `Build Variants` on Android studio
Source: https://mobikul.com/release-variant-of-app-enable-logcat-running-release-build-application/
It work me!
Can you try it