# Step through a release version in Android

Tags: android, debugging

Is it possible to debug a signed release of one's application on a commercial Android device that cannot be modified? One which does not have with debuggable = "true".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug apk signed for release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release)

Comment: @kabuko That question deals with a similar situation, but isn't a duplicate since it *does* specify debuggable = "true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. However, the application must have `android:debuggable="true"` in its manifest file.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release) that gives you more detail.

Comment: So, there is absolutely no way to get a market published app and duplicate the error a user sees unless you send them a debug version for them to test? Is this correct?

Comment: You can ask what steps they are taking when seeing the error and you can just reproduce the problem running your `debug` version of the app. However, if you do not have access to the source code for that particular application and you are wanting to help `debug` a problem someone is having... you are out of luck (if `android:debuggable="false"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the device with the debugger, than once the application is running it doesn't matter if it was from a signed apk, you can try to attach the debugger to the application process.