# Unable to debug the apk signed for release

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, apk

The question is a duplicate of [How to debug apk signed for release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release)

But I can't comment on that post. I have referred the [accepted answer posted by Sam Dozor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082383/1793718) for that question and followed all the steps. I could click the green bug too, to allow debugging for my app's process in the device. But I am still not able to step through the code where I have attached my debugger. The code is open in the workspace. I could debug the code in the device when run from eclipse without creating apk, but I want to debug the release apk since the issue happens only when the signed apk is installed on device.

Would there be something else to take care other than the steps mentioned?

Comment: just run your apk and the logcat still show all the process it makes with some change of your class name and method. but it wont have to be a problem