# Android app displays list on device but when downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, google-play

**Set up** - My Android app, on loading, calls a REST API to get json feed from a server running on Google App Engine. It parses this json and populates a list containing ItemListBaseAdaptor. I'm trying to figure out where it goes from here.

**Problem** - When I build and deploy this app on my device via USB, it works as expected. But, when, I upload and download this app from playstore, I see a blank screen.

**Observations** -

- I log the json response on Google App Engine in both cases and I see identical responses.
- On my Android app, I added some Toast notifications to see what happens when we try to translate json response to ItemListBaseAdaptor. I see no problem in both cases.
- I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, repackaging and publishing it a few times (as Alpha builds). Same result each time.

**What I could not figure out** - How do I debug or read logs from an app I download from playstore? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release) and I get stuck at step 8.

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Comment: You might be getting stuck because the app isn't debuggable - unless you uploaded a debuggable build to the app store.  Here's what I would do.  1. make a release build that's just like your play store one except debuggable 2. install it via adb 3. attach to the process from the IDE 4. find out what's happening.

Comment: I've done that with no luck so far. When I install via ADB it works. It;s only playstore where it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was minifyEnabled flag in Android Studio. I changed it from true to false and it started working.