# Android - Tracking release build crashes / exceptions / ANRs'

Tags: android, google-play, android-log

How do I check for errors or log errors in release version of my app?

Activity crashes the app in release version but working in debug version. How do I check for errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug apk signed for release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options before you:

**1.** If your app is already live, then the Play Store records all exceptions thrown by apps on connected devices. Log into your Google Play Store account and see [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=en).

**2.** If you need even more detail, the Google Play Services library has deeper support for crash analysis than what you normally get from the Play Store. See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions).

**3.** You can add a support package like [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary) that will provide real-time analysis for apps in the wild.

**4.** `Log.e()`, `Log.v()`, `Log.i()` and `Log.wtf()` emit log messages even in release mode, and can be observed in the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

Comment: I have the app in alpha mode right now. I tried adding 'android:debuggable="true"' but Play Store won't allow it to be uploaded if it's true.

Comment: Of course it won't allow that. I never asked you to try that. If you want log statements in release mode, try log.v or log.i

Comment: My app is crashing when I click a button that's supposed to take me to a new activity (intent). The button works in debug mode. How do I see the error in release version?

Comment: I don't think you know what you're saying

Comment: Log statements can be made visible in release mode.

Comment: How am I supposed to log an app crash? In debug version it logs itself.

Comment: But I solved my problem by another solution. I chose yours as the correct because your answer was elaborate but it didn't help me.

Comment: I added "buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true..." in gradle and generated a signed apk and installed that on my phone while connecting my phone to my PC with a USB. Android Studio's "Android Monitor" showed me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add **crash reporting libraries** like ACRA to check error logs in release mode.

Here is link for [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) library