# debuggable is true in release mode build?

Tags: android

`debuggable=true` in release mode apk. When I tried to hard code this property I am getting below error

> "Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and
>   release builds to automatically assign one".

So I updated build.gradle as below,

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true

    }
}
```

But nothing seems working. What I am doing wrong?
I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 and I have few flavors defined in build.gradle.

Comment: Please check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release

Comment: solution mentioned is not working for me. I am trying to set debuggable to false.

Comment: so you are able to debug your release build?

Comment: Yes. I can debug the app. Because androidmanifest contain debuggable property set to true.

Comment: show the manifest then

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
 </application>

Comment: are you sure that you are building `release` application, not `debug` one?

Comment: remove android:debuggable="true" from your manifest..

Comment: My manifest does not contain debugging=true property.

Comment: Yes it's release mode only

Answer (score 8):

testcoverageenabled = true was the problem. Changed to false and now debuggable=false working.

Comment: Do you need the `=` sign for debuggable?

Answer (score 0):

My personal observation. I tried the same in sample hello word app, then debuggable=true property is not added to android manifest.