# Android application behaves differently when download from Play Store

Tags: android, networking, google-play, adb

I have built an application that returns data when entering a Dutch license plate. The data it returns is taken from the API from the RDW who stores all this data. Now my problem is: When I push the application from my Android Studio via ADB it works perfectly. But when I publish the SAME application to the Play Store and download/install it from there it only works the first time when entering a license plate. The second time it does just spin the progress bar and returns to the home screen after around 10 seconds.

How is this possible?

Comment: check the log cat and add build config in Gradle with the release Keystore config then check debug you might know the reason

Comment: https://unsee.cc/nozisuge/ check this image and below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release

Comment: Are you using proguard for your release builds?

Answer (score 0):

You should test your **Signed APK** before uploading to the store. Then You can debug that signed apk in android studio by printing some log messages on the corresponding activity. Then you can trace the issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Just **uncheck Instant Run** in **settings** of Android Studio and then build and run that apk. For instant run option, go to **File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run**, then remove check of Enable Instant Run. After that run project again and make and use new apk. .I hope this solution work.