# Android Studio signed APK does not run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I have an Android app developed with Android Studio. I have managed to generate a signed APK, with the keystore that I also have used before, it installs fine however when I try to run it I get an error and it never runs.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the development version work fine ?  Try debug the apk and send us the error log

Comment: Yes the development version works absolutely fine. How can I debug the APK?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release

Comment: "I get an error": which one?

Comment: Do I generate a "release" or "debug" APK file?

Comment: when I change this bit in the gradle to the following, then at the time of generating the APK file I get this error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. `buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checked both Signature `Version v1 and v2` before making a`signed APK`

[image]

Comment: Both are ticked.