# When the application is published on the Google Play Store, the data from the API is not fetched from the hosting

Tags: android, laravel, flutter

Data provisioning to my app using Laravel api
Everything works as expected when you open the app from within Android Studio
The problem occurs after publishing the application on the Google Play Store
The problem is (not calling data from hosting)

The app is built with Flutter and Laravel

I had this problem in one of my applications I was using firebase
I copied sha1 and added it in firebase

But now I don't know what to do
I searched a lot and never found anything

Maybe I don't know what I'm looking for

Comment: did you add internet permission in manifest

Comment: Create a release build with [debuggable=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081877/how-to-debug-apk-signed-for-release) . and debug the issue . Then only u can find the exact problem its better than guessing game .

Comment: Do you use `Obfuscation` for release build?

Comment: are you using retrofit for calling data from your host!?

Comment: I deleted some permissions and deleted the internet permission by mistake, I will add it and upload the app to the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml?

Check also release mode run in Android Studio

Comment: I deleted some permissions and deleted the internet permission by mistake, I will add it and upload the app to the store

Comment: The problem, as I mentioned, is that the manifest file is free of internet permission. After adding the permission and publishing the application on the store, it works as expected. Thank you