# How to debug react native application in android device?

Tags: react-native, debugging, android-debug, react-native-debugger

I have installed the React native APK file on my android device. I am able to open the application on my android device. In my application, some functionalities are not working. I need to debug the code via my android device. How to debug the React native android application in a Real Android device. Does any third-party plugin need to install or not? Does anyone know the answer, please let me know.
Thanks & Regards,
Karthick

Comment: Open the project in Android Studio and debug as a normal native application

Comment: I am able to debug the code using the android emulator and chrome. That time my functionality is working fine. But, When I installed the APK on an android device. some functionalities are not working. So,  I need to check what scenario I get an error.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179527/13994039

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can debug via [React Native Debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging)